# Restricting an action to a single route/view in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have an existing page in Ember.js for flagged content and displays it. I want to have this content be drag-and-droppable. Doing this in a new model is as trivial as adding a sortOrder property and binding the values, but I want this to only apply to the model within this view. Any pointers? Can link to a JSbin if needed

Comment: Yes, ember.jsbin makes it easier to understand the issue.